# Beginner question: How do I integrate processing.js with a Rails 3.1 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, processing.js

Beginner rails/javascript question:

Let's say that I have a simple `Circle` model in a Rails 3.1 app with a `show` action/view. Each `Circle` has a property called `:radius` - an integer value.

When I view the `Circle` via its `show.html.erb` file, I want a very simple processing.js sketch to receive the radius of the circle and draw the circle on the page. I've already included processing.js in my app by saving the file in the `assets/javascripts` folder.

My simple processing.js sketch is in a file called `circle.js`. Its contents are:

```
// Setup the Processing Canvas  
void setup(){  
  size( 200, 200 );  
  strokeWeight( 10 );  
  frameRate( 15 );  
  X = width / 2;  
  Y = height / 2;
  radius = 10;      
}  

// Main draw loop  
void draw(){    
  // Fill canvas grey  
  background( 100 );  

  // Set stroke-color white  
  stroke(255);   

  // Draw circle  
  ellipse( X, Y, radius, radius );                    
}
```

1. How do I include the sketch into my show view as unobtrusively as possible and pass the radius value to it?
2. Where does the `circle.js` file go -- in the view folder or in the asset pipeline?
3. Does it need to be named `circle.js.erb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put circle.js into app/assets/javascripts.  It doesn't need to be called circle.js.erb, but it could be.

Comment: Ok - how do I get the circle.js file to grab the radius property for each circle I want to show? What if I want to show multiple circles on the same page?

Comment: You could do this a few different ways. One way that I would try is have a <script> tag that creates a variable, like: var circle_radii = [ 9, 12, 23 ];  Then your circle.js would have a function that checks to see if circle_radii is not undefined, if it's an Array, and then iterate through that list to create circles.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Due to the nature of including Processing.js files, I had to include an html partial and include the script in it. The variable work as you describe. The performance is terrible, however, so I'll look into another option, such as Rafaeljs. Thanks!